# How to say more cheerful in one word?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

Can I say cheerfuler ? Or is it better to say cheerfully. Like 'more good' -'better' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. **Cheerfuler** is not a word in English and, realistically speaking, no one would ever say that (for one, it's very difficult to pronounce). The adverb **cheerfully** means in a cheerful manner. It doesn't mean more cheerful. The reason why the comparative form of **good** is **better** has to do with the fact that the adjective **good** is not a regular adjective which means that its comparative form is not formed by preceding it with the word *more* (e.g. *more expensive*, *more beautiful* etc.) or by adding the suffix *-er* to the end of the word (e.g. *faster*, *stronger* etc.). Instead, it is formed irregularly by changing the word's morphological structure entirely: *good* becomes *better*. So, **more cheerful** is your only option.